# What is the difference between (to be) available and (to be) made available?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Consider for instance:

> It is vital that food **is made available** to the famine areas

OR

> It is vital that food **is available** to the famine areas.

Another example:

> Old sources of major components of Magenta **are still made available** on my GitHub.

OR

> Old sources of major components of Magenta **are still available** on my GitHub.

Comment: "Is available" refers to status.  It means to be in a state of availability, either currently or at the time it is needed.  It may already be available, in which case nothing needs to be done to make it that way.  "Is made available" refers to action.  It means that it is normally not available and action must be taken to make it available.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: No difference, apart from tiny change in sentiment

The difference between the two is small. When you say:

> Something is **made available** ...

It implies that someone has taken the effort to **make** it available. When you say:

> Something **is available** ...

It is more direct and removes a small piece of personality from the text, however for almost all circumstances they are the same as each other and I would use either although you will find that **is available** is more common because of it's directness.

Comment: Agreed.  The end result is the same, **to make** something **available** is an action, by someone, that results in a condition where that thing **is available**.  I don't know if one is more common than the other.  Instead you use these in different ways.

Comment: No, the two sentences are completely different. What does "removes a small piece of personally to the text" even mean?? I'm afraid you have missed a basic grammar point here...

Comment: Sorry that was an error, I meant "personality" not "personally" .

Answer (score 1):

The difference between: to be made available and to be available is the difference between a  passive and an active verb.

Food **is made available [by relief organizations**].= A PASSIVE sentence
or:

Food is available.=ACTIVE sentence

That said, this sentence beginning with /it is vital/:
It is vital that food is available in famine areas really should really be phrased using the "subjunctive":

**It is vital that food be available** to the famine areas. [active]

**It is vital that food be made available** to the famine areas. [passive]